# Finding all 5 digit numbers

Tags: html, regex, dreamweaver, digits

Just moved to a new job, and my job is to retrofit schema to about 42,000 html web pages. I need to find all zip codes, which all happen to be in the same format. Each instance is only found once on each page so that makes it easier.

The format is:

```
, 72005,
```

I would like to find all instances of:

```
, #####,
```

and replace them with:

```
, <span itemprop="postalCode">72005<span>,
```

Tools of the trade are search and replace in Dreamweaver. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: , <span itemprop="postalCode">72005</span>,

Comment: try to convert it to a dynamic language instead. otherwise you will ask for a new regex to find that new format.

Answer (score 1):

With regex checked in the replace all you can try this.

## Find

```
, ([0-9]{5}),
```

## Replace

```
, <span itemprop="postalCode">$1<span>,
```